# Galleria: Custom Next and Previous link

Tags: javascript, slider, galleria

I need to make some divs my custom controllers for Galleria because I need them to work outside of slider container.

Is there a way using Javascript or other to make galleria known that for example: div with the id "#Right" behaves like the "next image" button?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the extend option: 
http://galleria.io/docs/options/extend/ & http://galleria.io/docs/api/methods/

```
Galleria.run('#galleria', {
extend: function () {
  var gallery = this;
  $('#right').click(function() {
    gallery.next();
  });
  $('#left').click(function() {
    gallery.prev();
  });
}
});
```